# Update managed document without changing the version

Tags: marklogic

I have used **Library services API** to insert documents into `MarkLogic`. There are scenarios where in I need to just save the changes done without checkin. That means save the changes into current version itself without incrementing the version number. Have seen such facilities in some **CMIS** specs, where it provides out of the box solution for checkin of the document with same version. Could not find any such similar **API** in `MarkLogic`. Alternate option I could think of is unmanage the managed document, use **xdmp** functions to perform update and remanage the content. But this would loose the previous versions. Are there any other alternate ways of doing this?

Comment: I am sure there are some tricks to be played here to make this happen without loosing your versions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried to simply use the xdmp update functions and thus bypass DLS? For example you could use `xdmp:node-replace` to replace the root element of a document. The docs say that you "must" use DLS functions for updates, but I think what that means is that non-DLS updates won't be managed by DLS.

Let's try.

```
(: new managed document :)
import module namespace dls = "http://marklogic.com/xdmp/dls" 
  at "/MarkLogic/dls.xqy";
dls:document-insert-and-manage('test', true(), <test id="1"/>)
=> ()

import module namespace dls = "http://marklogic.com/xdmp/dls" 
  at "/MarkLogic/dls.xqy";

dls:document-is-managed('test'),
dls:document-history('test')
=>
true
<dls:document-history uri="test" xmlns:dls="http://marklogic.com/xdmp/dls">
  <dls:version>
    <dls:version-id>1</dls:version-id>
    <dls:document-uri>test</dls:document-uri>
    <dls:latest>true</dls:latest>
    <dls:created>2013-03-15T10:22:35.642645-07:00</dls:created>
    <dls:author>9712740001723797867</dls:author>
    <dls:annotation/>
    <dls:deleted>false</dls:deleted>
  </dls:version>
</dls:document-history>
```

Looks good. Let's try an unmanaged update.

```
xdmp:node-replace(doc('test')/test, <test id="2"/>)
=> ()

doc('test')
=> <test id="2"/>

import module namespace dls = "http://marklogic.com/xdmp/dls" 
  at "/MarkLogic/dls.xqy";

dls:document-is-managed('test'),
dls:document-history('test')
=>
true
<dls:document-history uri="test" xmlns:dls="http://marklogic.com/xdmp/dls">
  <dls:version>
    <dls:version-id>1</dls:version-id>
    <dls:document-uri>test</dls:document-uri>
    <dls:latest>true</dls:latest>
    <dls:created>2013-03-15T10:22:35.642645-07:00</dls:created>
    <dls:author>9712740001723797867</dls:author>
    <dls:annotation/>
    <dls:deleted>false</dls:deleted>
  </dls:version>
</dls:document-history>
```

So the update worked, but the document history still shows version 1. That was what you wanted, right?

Now, I did this as the admin user. With a non-admin user you might have to grant some extra privileges - or it might be cleaner to create an amp. That could be used to guard against accidental unmanaged updates.

Comment: I had tried this but it had not worked. I am not sure if i had used admin role or had sufficient privileges.  This is  exactly what I wanted. Would try it by assigning proper privilege. Thanks a ton :)